# .htaccess rewrite is not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change the URL of my site:

```
http://example.com/clinicdetails.php?url=/diet-clinic-in-punjabi-bagh.html
```

to look like this:

```
http://example.com/clinicdetails.php/diet-clinic-in-punjabi-bagh.html
```

My code in `.htaccess` file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /clinicdetails.php?url=$1 [L]
```

However, this is not working (no error) on my localhost and also not on the shared hosting servers. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Is clinicdetails.php executed? What is `$_GET{'url']`?

Comment: check /etc/apache2/sites-available/default configured properly or not it should be <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: @MrTux i have a table and $_GET['url'] is used to get data  from the table which is used to show the data so yes the page is being executed!

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap  but my server does not show me the apache2 directory in the /etc/ folder. it is an shared hosting.forgive me if i said something wrong here i am newbie here!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /clinicdetails.php?url=$1 [L]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* is failing to match the given URL because of the start of string anchor `^`. Whilst you don't have slashes in the path segment you are trying to match, you do in the rest of the URL. So, try the following:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)\.html$ /clinicdetails.php?url=/$1 [L]
```

I've also changed the `*` to `+`, since the filename is at least 1 char. A more specific regex is better.

To map to your desired URL, you would also seem to require a slash prefix on the URL param value. ie. `url=/$1`